# multiple auth with django-social-auth

Tags: django, authentication

I have a django (v1.2.5) project with 2 apps.

I authenticate the user in the first app with regular Django User.

I want to be able to login into the second app with django-social-auth (v0.4.2) when the User will be some Contact model in my second app.

So my question is: How can I make /app1/login go to regular django login of the first app and
/app2/login go to django-social-auth login page to the second app?

Thanks, Alex A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question answer is:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    ('^app1/', include('app1.urls')),
    ('^app2/', include('app2.urls')),
)
```

Then in `app1.urls`:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url('^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='app1_login'),
)
```

And in `app2.urls`:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url('^login/$', 'app2.views.login', name='app2_login'),
)
```

But this is just a basic usage of Django... Clarify your problem, please.

Comment: Thanks. But what should I write in app2.views.login? Besides, I want django-social-auth to deal it for me. I mean - login, logout, redirections. Is there a way to to that? Maybe I should define another LOGIN_URL in settings and have my decorators accordingly or something like that?

Comment: You need to set up `django-social-auth` as it documented (in particular, add URLs entries) and then overwrite `social_auth.views.complete` to perform additional checks.  Look how it works in `django-social-auth` here: https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/social_auth/views.py#L37